# How to load data in Winforms asynchronously using Task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

I have a Winforms C# based MDI application and I have 3 Forms

1. MainForm which is my parent form
2. Child form which is the child of the above mentioned form
3. BaseView both the above forms are inherited from this base class

If you see in my BaseView, I am using Task to load the data in the background thread without freezing the UI, which works fine and the app quickly shows up. Now the problem is that while this data loading is happening in the background I am opening my child form but the child form is unable to get the Db connection because the background thread is still working, is there anyway that I can do kind of signalling to my child form that now the background Db connection has been set and now the child form can load the data. 
Or shall I change the way I am trying to achieve this.

Please advice.

```
 public partial class BaseView : Form
    {

        public BaseView()
        {
            var firstTimeInitializationTask = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => { FirstTimeInitialization(); });
            firstTimeInitializationTask.Start();
        }

        private void FirstTimeInitialization()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000); // just put this for testing purpose
            DbConnection.Connect(CommonRoutines.DbConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: show how the child form is called.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. Don't use Task.Start like that. Apart from that it's impossible to answer because you didn't post anything that can run in the background. In general, ADO.NET has asynchronous methods like `ExecuteQueryAsync` etc

Comment: Why not use a simple bool flag to signal that the task is completed. Your child form could simply check if the flag is true.

Comment: `DbConnection.Connect` is *extremely* suspicious by the way. Having a global connection is a serious bug. Connections should be opened right before they are used and closed immediatelly when no longer needed. `DbConnection` is the name of the abstract base class for all ADO.NET connection classes too. Those classes all have `OpenAsync` methods to open without blocking

Comment: @adam.k that would only lead to race conditions.

Comment: @Shax what are you trying to do? What is `FirstTimeInitialization` supposed to do and why do that in the *constructor*? Removing the global connection will solve the immediate problem and a lot of others as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in FirstTimeInitialization method i am only loading the data which is required to load only the first time, I am using Devexpress.Xpo ORM and that's what I have found in their documentation to load once at the start of the application.

Comment: @Shax if that is meant to be called once at start of application why is it in a base class used by multiple derived classes that will be called more than once? Looks like you are mixing cross-cutting concerns.

Comment: @Nkosi, no to avoid this I have created multiple BaseView Constructor, 1 for MainForm and the secondone for the child forms

Comment: We would not have known that from what was shown, but either way, that is a poor design. This is turning into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi, can you suggest me what should I do in that case ?

Comment: Trying to do that is too broad given the limited information provided. Provide a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates the issue so that a proper solution can be suggested.